# Merging Values from Two Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models in my Rails 6 app, `Users`, `Friends`.

`Friend` has two attributes, `user_id` and `friend_id`, both are meant to hold `User.id`s (Friend is just to connect two users).

I'm trying to build a query to determine who a user's friends are.

Since a User can be connected to another User in a Friend record as either the user_id or friend_id, I'm trying to:

1. Find all the records where the User is the user_id or friend_id
2. Merge the user_ids and friend_ids into a single array (so I can search for user records using the ids)

This is what I have now:

```
    def self.find_friends(user_id)
      @friends= Friend.where("user_id = ? or friend_id = ?", user_id, user_id).pluck(:user_id, :friend_id)
      @friend_ids = @friends.user_id + @friends.friend_id
      @users = User.where(id: [@friend_ids])
    end
```

I'm doing something wrong in `@friend_ids = @friends.user_id + @friends.friend_id` because I'm getting the error:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'user_id' for <Connection::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00000000100002e8>`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of your query should be an array (since you are using pluck).
By filtering out the duplicated results (uniq) and make it one array (using flatten) and removing the user_id itself, you will end up with an array of the friend's ids.

```
def self.find_friends(user_id)
   @friends= Friend.where("user_id = ? or friend_id = ?", user_id, user_id).pluck(:user_id, :friend_id).uniq.flatten
   @friend_ids = @friends - [user_id]
   @users = User.where(id: [@friend_ids])
end
```